# Why does connecting to '127.0.0.1' work whilst 'localhost' fails?

Tags: postgresql, permissions, psql, connectivity

I have noticed that although the listening host in `postgresql.conf` is  `localhost` connecting to a database via `psql` fails unless the host is changed `127.0.0.1`. I have also noticed `MySQL` display the same trait on occasion.

Is there some difference between `127.0.0.1` and `localhost` which causes the database connections to be treated differently?

Comment: Are you running more than one database your system? Do you have more than one instance of the database running?

Comment: Generally it's because `localhost` resolves to an IPv6 address such as `::1`. In any case, when `psql` fails to connect, it displays an error message which should be included in your question.

Comment: This question is lacking basic information. Your OS? Your Postgres version? Which setting in `postgresql.conf` *exactly*? Connecting with psql (same version?)  from where exactly? How exactly? Fails how exactly? Please be more clear.

Answer (score 6):

this has nothing to do with databases. its how you os resolves the domain name in this case 'localhost'

you /etc/hosts file should have an entry for localhost as below if you don't have it , then adding this entry will resolve your issue

```
 127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain
```

Comment: I have got `127.0.0.1  localhost` in my /etc/hosts file, but not `localhost.localdomain`, and my pg_hba.conf files contains `127.0.0.1` but not `localhost`. Could these be factors?

Comment: yes, since you are specifying actual IP it expects you to  use the same. In case if you use a domain name for e.g.: localhost , only then it will try to resolve. and in that case also, it will expect you to use localhost.

it is always good to use ip since , someone could edit the hosts file as below and 

     `192.168.x.x localhost localhost.localdomain.com`

so now you localhost is the local any more

Answer (score 2):

If you are connecting via `psql -h 127.0.0.1` or `psql -h localhost` or just `psql`, it will determine HOW `psql` connects (either via TCP/IP or to a local socket, respectively).

postgres' `pg_hba.conf` file may have an entry allowing to connect to TCP/IP (a line starting with `host`), but not to a socket (a line starting with `local`).

Review your records in that file and verify that localhost is allowed to connect. It is likely located in the same directory that your `postgres.conf` file is in.

You can find more details [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11913897/whats-the-difference-between-local-and-localhost-connection-types-in-pg-hba)

I should add that I have encountered this behavior previously and it turned out that I had removed the `local` line from my pg_hba.conf file.  When I added it back in, it worked fine.

Comment: I will update my answer to be slightly more specific..  Please see this thread:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11913897/whats-the-difference-between-local-and-localhost-connection-types-in-pg-hba

Answer (score 0):

Check your HOSTS file to see if you didn't screw it up (duplicate lines, wrong lines, etc). It should only have this in it:
`127.0.0.1 localhost`

Comment: ... at least the only line related to the issue.  It's not uncommon to have a bunch of entries there, like in my case, for some VMs and other stuff.